# No se me actualiza mi base de datos con UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema la base de datos no se me actualiza al presionar el botón ,mi código es este

Formulario

```
    <?php
    extract($_GET);
    $server = "localhost";
              $usuario = "root";
             $contraseña = "";
             $bd = "bdpagina";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contraseña, $bd)
or die("error en la conexion");

    $sql="SELECT * FROM contribuyente WHERE id=$id";
    require("connect_db.php");
    $ressql=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row ($ressql)){
            $id=$row[0];
            $nombre=$row[1];
            $rut=$row[2];
            $email=$row[3];
            $phone=$row[4];
            $direccion=$row[5];
            $poste=$row[6];
            $mensaje=$row[7];
            $comentario=$row[9];
            $estado=$row[8];
            $fecha=$row[10];
            $servicio=$row[11];
            $fechares=$row[12];

        }


    ?>
              <br><form action="creaPDF.php" method="post">
                    <div>
                        <label for="nombre">¿Desea enviar el reporte?</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label for="nombre">Folio:</label>
                   <input type="text" name="id" value= "<?php echo $id ?>" readonly="readonly"></div>
                   <div>
                  <br> <label for="nombre">Correo:</label>
                   <input type="text" name="email" style="" value= "<?php echo $email ?>" readonly="readonly">
              </div>
                   <br><input type="submit" name ="recibir" value="Enviar Reporte" class="btn btn-success btn-primary">
                  </form>
```

El siguiente código lo que realiza  es crear un PDF y enviarlo automáticamente al email , lo envía y y lo crea bien pero ademas quiero que al enviar el pdf el registro cambien de estado con un UPDATE .

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Enviar email con archivo adjunto y cambiar estado</title>
</head>
<body> 
<?php
extract($_POST);
$server = "localhost";
              $usuario = "root";
             $contraseña = "";
             $bd = "bdpagina";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contraseña, $bd)
or die("error en la conexion");
$sentencia = "UPDATE contribuyente SET estado = 'cerrada' WHERE contribuyente. id = '$id'";
 ?>
 <?php
   include_once('PDF.php');
   include_once('myDBC.php');

   $mat = $_POST['id'];
   $email=$_POST['email'];
   $pdf = new PDF();
   $pdf->AddPage('P', 'Letter'); 
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12); 


   $pdf->Cell(40,7,'ESTADO SOLICITUD',0, 1 , ' L ');
   $pdf->Ln();

   $pdf->ImprimirTexto('textoFijo.txt'); 
   $consultaPersona = new myDBC();
   $datosPersona = $consultaPersona->seleccionar_persona($mat);
   $cabecera = array("Estado","Folio","Nombre","Rut","Email", "Telefono", "solicitud", "Observacion");
  $pdf->tabla($cabecera,$datosPersona); 
   $pdf->Output("adjunto-temp.pdf","F"); 
   function comprobar_email($email) {
   return (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ? 1 : 0;
    }

  if (isset($_POST['recibir'])) {
  if (comprobar_email($_POST['email'])) {
    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->From = "daniela.milla95@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Modulo alumbrado publico";
    $mail->Subject = "Respuesta a solicitud";
    $mail->Body = "Estimado(a) se le ah enviado la siguiente informacion de Modulo de solicitudes alumbrado publico, se adjunta documento!!!";
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->AddAddress($_POST['email'], "User Name");
    $archivo = 'prueba.pdf';
    $mail->AddAttachment('adjunto-temp.pdf');
    $mail->Send();
    echo '<script>alert("REPORTE ENVIADO")</script>';
    echo "<script>location.href='admin.php'</script>";
   }
    else {
    echo '<p>El email introducido no es correcto!</p>';
   }
   }
  ?>
```

Lo que quiero es que al enviar el correo el de la solicitud cambie a cerrada Gracias

Comment: Tu variable sentencia donde la usas, parece que simplemente declaras el statement (Update) pero nunca dices que lo aplicarás a una conexión.
if ($conexion->query($sentencia) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

Comment: Gracias eso era :D